# PushStreamContent and exceptions in the middle of streaming/serializing

Tags: asp.net-web-api

We're using PushStreamContent to stream some large lumps with Content-Disposition headers set and the like.  As a number of people have discovered, the drawback is what happens when something goes wrong in the streaming?

At the very least, we were trying to get the error logged on our side so someone could follow up.

Recently, I ran into a weird situation.  Putting a try/catch around the streaming function worked well enough for errors encountered before you actually started streaming (i.e. errors in sql queries and the like), but if the error occurred later (like in the serialization), the catch block doesn't fire.

Would anyone have any idea why that is?

e.g.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
try
{
    response.Content = new PushStreamContent((stream, content, context) =>
    {
        using (XmlWriter rWriter = PrepForXmlOutput(stream))
        {
            rpt.GenerateXmlReport(rWriter, reportParams, true);
        }
    }, "EventReport", extension);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // The first step of GenerateXmlReport() is to run the sql; 
    // if the error happens there, this fires and will log the exception
    // if the error happens later, during the result serialization, this does NOT fire
    Log.Error(e);
}

return response;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hate it when I see the answer just after I hit Post.

Try/catch around the outside only covers until I return the HttpResponseMessage.  When/where I get the exception depends on how far the inner method gets before that return happens.

The try/catch needed to be on the inner call (the one where all the work happens) to cover the whole lifecycle.